# 150 TPS for 30 users with 50,000 requests in 6 hrs

Tags: jmeter

Suppose we have to achieve 150 TPS for 30 users with 50,000 requests in jmeter where user runs for 6hrs. 
I want to hit 3 HTTP request in this scenario.

Can you please suggest how can i configure in such a way?

I have tired to create thread group where users are 25 and duration is 28,800 but i am unable to achieve above part.

I need 150 tps for 50,000 requests in 6hrs

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to execute 100 000 requests in 8 hours with 25 users - you need to perform approximately 3.5 TPS. In this case use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) to limit the requests execution rate to 208.3 requests per minute
2. If you want to achieve 150 TPS rate - I doubt you will be able to do this with 25 users (unless response time of your application is 0.16 ms). You might want to allocate more virtual users in order to reach 150 TPS using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination. However given 150 TPS and 8 hours test duration you will get 4 320 000 requests.

So double check your [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)/[NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) as the requirements you listed above are mutually exclusive and cannot be put together.